# What does the while modifier mean in clojure?

Tags: clojure

The following shows that the modifier "while" means the iterate will stop once an element match the check:

```
=> (for [x [3 2 3 1] :while (< x 3)] x)
()
```

However why the following not stop iterating ? it should return an empty list in my (wrong) understanding.

```
=> (for [x [3 2 3 1] y [:a :b] :while (< x 3)] [x y])
([2 :a] [2 :b] [1 :a] [1 :b])
```

Actually it turns out that there is no difference between the "when" and the "while" modifier in this case.

```
=> (for [x [3 2 3 1] y [:a :b] :when (< x 3)] [x y])
([2 :a] [2 :b] [1 :a] [1 :b])
```

How that happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:while` and `:when` modifiers are always checked after the binding immediately preceding them, and only apply to the iteration of *that* loop. If you want to stop binding new `x`s, you need to put the `:while` after the `x` clause, not the `y` clause.

Comment: Thanks amalloy, you partially clear my confusion in that "modifiers are always checked after the binding immediately preceding them". However according to this rule, due to my mistakenly put the modifier behind the 2nd loop, it should return all the composition of [x y] instead of the fact it filtering out the x=3. Why ?

Comment: Every time it chooses a y, it checks if x is three or more. If so, it skips all the rest of the ys, and then goes back to try a new x. Since it skipped all the ys, no x/y pairs exist with x >= 3.

Comment: So the "skipping the rest" feature of the _while_ only takes effect on the loop(the y loop in my case) preceding it, Right ? This explains why the _while_ in my 2nd example above act right the same way as a _when_. Thank you very much. I've asked 2 times on stackoverflow about the difference between _while_ and _when_. If I were a native English speaker I may not make so much noise here ;-).